# pigpio, update xfer.txBuf

Tags: c++, pigpio

Question refactored:

Im currently struggling to understand how to update the transmit FIFO of the bsc_xfer.

For reference:

Slave side:

---

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int GPIO = gpioInitialise();

if(GPIO)
{

    bsc_xfer_t xfer;
  
    xfer.control = (0x09<<16) | 0x305; 
    int status = bscXfer(&xfer);
    std::cout<<"\nstatus: "<<status<<std::endl;
    
    if(status >= 0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            status = bscXfer(&xfer);
            if (status)
            {
                if(xfer.rxCnt > 0)
                {
                    
                    printf("\nRxCnt: %d RxVal: %x\n", xfer.rxCnt, xfer.rxBuf[0]);
                    switch(xfer.rxBuf[0])
                    {
                        case 0x00:
                        memcpy(xfer.txBuf, "ABCD", 4);
                        xfer.txCnt = 4;
                        break;
                        
                        case 0x01:
                        memcpy(xfer.txBuf, "FGHI", 4);
                        xfer.txCnt = 4;
                        break;
                        
                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                    memset( xfer.rxBuf, '\0', BSC_FIFO_SIZE );
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
}
```

---

Master side:

---

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int GPIO = gpioInitialise();

if(GPIO)
{
    int handler = i2cOpen(1, 9, 0);
    
    std::cout<<"\nHandler: "<<handler<<std::endl;
    
    if(handler >= 0)
    {
        int wr = i2cWriteByte(handler, 0x00);
        
        std::cout<<"\nwr: "<<wr<<std::endl;
        
        if(wr >= 0)
        {
            char buf[5] = "1111";
           
            int test = i2cReadDevice(handler, buf, 4);
            
            std::cout<<"\ntest: "<<test<<std::endl;
            
            if(test >= 0)
            {
                std::cout<<"\nReceived: " << buf;
            }
            
            std::cout<<std::endl;
            
            wr = i2cWriteByte(handler, 0x01);
        
            std::cout<<"\nwr(2): "<<wr<<std::endl;
        
            if(wr >= 0)
            {
                test = i2cReadDevice(handler, buf, 4);
            
                std::cout<<"\ntest(2): "<<test<<std::endl;
            
                if(test >= 0)
                {
                    std::cout<<"\nReceived: "<<buf;
                }
            
                std::cout<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"\nGPIO init error"<<std::endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

expected output:

> Received: ABCD
>
> Received: FGHI

actual output:

> Received: ABCD
>
> Received: AFGH

Question: I'm missing how to reset the Tx fifo correctly, is there a proper way or am I touching something not covered by the lib?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your code.

I would suggest you use pigs from the command line (if possible).  That would give you a feel for what will/should happen.

Remember you need to fill the TX buffer before the other side requests the data.  There is no way Linux/pigpio will be fast enough to construct the message on the fly.  So the remote side should ask for the data in one transaction and read it in another a few milliseconds later.

Comment: I think I got it working; some points, I indeed ask the data by writing a byte then giving some ms before reading (even 0.1 ms works), I let it run for an hour and simple logs shows no error. 2nd points: this code misses all gpioTerminate / closing due to extraction from real file; 3rd point, I've been reading the sources and realized that I totaly missunderstood what txCnt meant, its not dynamically decreased, (i.e. become 0 once all bytes are sent)

Comment: @Ebya It is very hard to clearly document code.  Any documentation updates are welcome!

Comment: one strange point: it seems that the 0.1ms between write & read on master->slave is only ok on Pi-zero, Rpi3 needs 1ms (nothing else running on it); Second point: is there a way to clean TX fifo without setting the BK bit in control to 1 ?

Comment: @Ebya You wrote: "*I think I got it working...*". Please create an answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.